# Easy way to remove ghost text default value on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script code below makes ghost text

```
$('.ghost-text').each(function(){
    var d = $(this).val();
    $(this).focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == d){
            $(this).val('').removeClass('ghost-text');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).val(d).addClass('ghost-text');
        }
    });
});
```

But on submit it passes that default ghost value. How to delete it on submit?

Comment: Ghost text? Plz define for me. (placeholder??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its better to use a placeholder:

```
<input type="text" id="myTxt" placeholder="enter something..."/>
```

Or if you want to stick with your js:

```
 if($.browser.msie){
    $('.ghost-text').each(function(){
        var d = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        $(this).focus(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == d){
                $(this).val('').removeClass('ghost-text');
            }
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == ''){
                $(this).val(d).addClass('ghost-text');
            }
        });
    });   

 $('form').submit(function(){
    $('.ghost-text').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))
            $(this).val('');
    });
});
}
```

Comment: I did <input id="search" type="text" name="cities" placeholder=="CITY/AREA" class="ghost-text" /> and now I see `="CITY/AREA"` in the input

Comment: That's what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Check your '=' or is that a typo in the comment?

Comment: ah yes sorry. Another problem I still see `CITY/AREA` on focus

Comment: FF. Yes it clears but preffer to do that on focus if possible

Comment: It's not possible. Because that's the default behavior of placeholder attribute. Its controlled by the browser.

Comment: By the way, check the search textbox on the top right of this page. You can see the use of placeholder. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $(".ghost-text").each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ghostTexts = $('.ghost-text');

    ghostTexts.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            d = $(this).val();

        $this.on({
            'focus': function(){
                if ($this.val() == d){
                    $this.val('').removeClass('ghost-text');
                }
            },
            'blur': function() {
                if ($this.val() == ''){
                    $this.val(d).addClass('ghost-text');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('yourForm').on('submit', function() {
        ghostTexts.val('');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call 'ghot text' watermark and able to use HTML5, use placeholder attribute instead:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="My ghost text" />
```

If 'ghost text' as nothing to do with watermark and dont want to submit it, you can use this instead:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('.ghost-text',this).each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('name');
    });
});
```